# Почему я получаю от YouTube два видео в разных форматах?

Tags: java, видео, youtube, youtube-api

Я использую библиотеку vGet для скачивания видео из YouTube. Сначала всё было нормально и я скачивал свой положенный формат .mp4, но теперь, не понятно из-за чего, скачивается два варианта видео: в формате .mp4 и .webm. Причём .mp4 не запускается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код (делал по [примерам](https://github.com/varundbest/vget) под свою реализацию):

```
package ua.youtube.downloader;

import com.github.axet.vget.VGet;
import com.github.axet.vget.info.VGetParser;
import com.github.axet.vget.info.VideoFileInfo;
import com.github.axet.vget.info.VideoInfo;
import com.github.axet.vget.vhs.VimeoInfo;
import com.github.axet.vget.vhs.YouTubeInfo;
import com.github.axet.wget.SpeedInfo;
import com.github.axet.wget.info.DownloadInfo;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class DownloadVideoManager {
    private Frame mainFrame;
    private String pathStr;
    private String url;
    private String sizeVideo;
    private VGet v;
    private VideoFileInfo videoFileInfo;
    private File targetFile;
    private int progress;
    private String endFormat = ".mp4";

    public DownloadVideoManager(Frame mainFrame, String url, String pathStr){
        this.mainFrame = mainFrame;
        this.url = url;
        this.pathStr = pathStr;
    }

    public DownloadVideoManager(){}

    public void downloadVideo() {
        File path = new File(pathStr);
        final AtomicBoolean stop = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        URL web = null;
        try {
            web = new URL(url);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        VGetParser user = VGet.parser(web);
        VideoInfo videoinfo = user.info(web);
        v = new VGet(videoinfo, path);
        VGetStatus notify = new VGetStatus(videoinfo);

        v.extract(user, stop, notify);
        videoFileInfo = v.getVideo().getInfo().get(0);
        System.out.println("Title: " + videoinfo.getTitle());
        List<VideoFileInfo> list = videoinfo.getInfo();
        sizeVideo = getSizeVideo(list.get(0));
        mainFrame.setSizeVideo(getSizeVideo(list.get(0)));
        if (list != null) {
            for (VideoFileInfo d : list) {
                System.out.println("Size of video: " + getSizeVideo(d));
            }
        }
        v.download(user, stop, notify);
    }

    private String getSizeVideo(VideoFileInfo videoFileInfo){
        return (int)(double) videoFileInfo.getLength()/(1024*1024)+" mb";
    }


    class VGetStatus implements Runnable {
        VideoInfo videoinfo;
        long last;

        Map<VideoFileInfo, SpeedInfo> map = new HashMap<VideoFileInfo, SpeedInfo>();

        public VGetStatus(VideoInfo i) {
            this.videoinfo = i;
        }

        public SpeedInfo getSpeedInfo(VideoFileInfo dinfo) {
            SpeedInfo speedInfo = map.get(dinfo);
            if (speedInfo == null) {
                speedInfo = new SpeedInfo();
                speedInfo.start(dinfo.getCount());
                map.put(dinfo, speedInfo);
            }
            return speedInfo;
        }

        public void run() {
            List<VideoFileInfo> dinfoList = videoinfo.getInfo();

            // notify app or save download state
            // you can extract information from DownloadInfo info;
            switch (videoinfo.getState()) {
                case EXTRACTING:
                case EXTRACTING_DONE:
                case DONE:
                    if (videoinfo instanceof YouTubeInfo) {
                        YouTubeInfo i = (YouTubeInfo) videoinfo;
                        System.out.println(videoinfo.getState() + " " + i.getVideoQuality());
                    } else if (videoinfo instanceof VimeoInfo) {
                        VimeoInfo i = (VimeoInfo) videoinfo;
                        System.out.println(videoinfo.getState() + " " + i.getVideoQuality());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("downloading unknown quality");
                    }
                    for (VideoFileInfo d : videoinfo.getInfo()) {
                        SpeedInfo speedInfo = getSpeedInfo(d);
                        speedInfo.end(d.getCount());
                        System.out.println(String.format("file:%d - %s (%s)", dinfoList.indexOf(d), d.targetFile,
                                formatSpeed(speedInfo.getAverageSpeed())));
                    }
                    break;
                case ERROR:
                    System.out.println(videoinfo.getState() + " " + videoinfo.getDelay());

                    if (dinfoList != null) {
                        for (DownloadInfo dinfo : dinfoList) {
                            System.out.println("file:" + dinfoList.indexOf(dinfo) + " - " + dinfo.getException() + " delay:"
                                    + dinfo.getDelay());
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case RETRYING:
                    System.out.println(videoinfo.getState() + " " + videoinfo.getDelay());

                    if (dinfoList != null) {
                        for (DownloadInfo dinfo : dinfoList) {
                            System.out.println("file:" + dinfoList.indexOf(dinfo) + " - " + dinfo.getState() + " "
                                    + dinfo.getException() + " delay:" + dinfo.getDelay());
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                case DOWNLOADING:
                    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if (now - 1000 > last) {
                        last = now;

                        String parts = "";

                        for (VideoFileInfo dinfo : dinfoList) {
                            SpeedInfo speedInfo = getSpeedInfo(dinfo);
                            speedInfo.step(dinfo.getCount());

                            List<DownloadInfo.Part> pp = dinfo.getParts();
                            if (pp != null) {
                                // multipart download
                                for (DownloadInfo.Part p : pp) {
                                    if (p.getState().equals(DownloadInfo.Part.States.DOWNLOADING)) {
                                        parts += String.format("part#%d(%.2f) ", p.getNumber(),
                                                p.getCount() / (float) p.getLength());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            String speedVideo = formatSpeed(speedInfo.getCurrentSpeed());
                            System.out.println(String.format("file1:%d - %s %.2f %s (%s)", dinfoList.indexOf(dinfo),
                                    videoinfo.getState(), dinfo.getCount() / (float) dinfo.getLength(), parts,
                                    speedVideo));
                            mainFrame.setSpeedVideo(speedVideo);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    public static String formatSpeed(long s) {
        if (s > 0.1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024) {
            float f = s / 1024f / 1024f / 1024f;
            return String.format("%.1f GB/s", f);
        } else if (s > 0.1 * 1024 * 1024) {
            float f = s / 1024f / 1024f;
            return String.format("%.1f MB/s", f);
        } else {
            float f = s / 1024f;
            return String.format("%.1f kb/s", f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А кодек точено есть в системе?